# How to start the timer only after condition is met in Java

Tags: java, timer

I am comparing two values 'a' and 'b'. These values are retrieved in realtime via an API.
I want to implement an alert when the value in 'a' continue to remain higher than 'b' after 2 seconds.

This is my code

```
public class CheckValues extends TimerTask {

  if(a>b)
{
System.out.println("Value exceeded. Going to recheck in 2 seconds");
//I want to then re-check this condition after 2 seconds by something as below. 'a' and 'b' continue to get updated.
 public void run() {
        // schedule for 2 seconds and recheck with latest values if a is still greater than b, then trigger an alert
    }
}
   
}
```

This doesn't work. Any suggestions how to re-perform the check. I don't want to use sleep because I am consuming this data in realtime via an API and don't want to miss updates by sleeping.

Comment: This is not even a valid Java syntax. You have to check this condition outside this class and schedule rechecks there.

Comment: how do i schedule rechecks in that case? wont i have to extend Timertask for a class? Sorry for asking these questions but not sure how to reschedule outside the above class. for eg if i use a function and in that function i call the same condition, how to recheck there?

Answer (score 0):

To run a task repeatedly in the background, use the Executors framework. The `Timer`/`TimerTask` classes were years ago supplanted by the executor service classes.

Define a `Runnable` class that carries an `Instant` member field. The `run` method checks for equality of your two values. If equal, set the instant with `Instant.now()`. If not equal, clear the instant by setting to null or some marker value such as `Instant.EPOCH`. If equal, and the instant is already set, compare to current moment to see if two seconds have elapsed: `Duration.between( then , Instant.now() ).toSeconds() > 2`.

Submit an instance of this `Runnable` to a `ScheduledExecutorService` to run repeatedly. Specify how often you want to execute the `run` method of your runnable object.

All of these pieces have been covered on Stack Overflow many times. Search to learn more.